# Android Radio Button left padding to 0

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

Need help with radio button

My xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:text="Hello" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:text="World" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

There is this space on the left between the circle and the left side of the linear layout. How do I get rid of that space? In TextViews setting minWidth to 0dp does the trick but I could not do it for RadioButtons. ANy ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are few ways to do it, you can try this

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp" 
    >
```

...
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"

does it do what you need ?

Comment: That worked but kind of feel hacky to me. Is there no other way other than extending RadioButton?

Comment: well other way around is to set button null and define your own circle drawable then set the margins you need like this 
android:button="@null"
android:drawableRight="@drawable/yout_circle"
android:padding="12dp"

but I doubt that this is better way then previous "hack"

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you wants is something like this

```
        <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:text="Hello" />
```

and you dont need

```
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
```

You can play with

```
android:layout_margin
```

until you get what you want.

You can get more information about margin attributes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)

I hope this helps you!

Comment: That worked but kind of feel hacky to me. Is there no other way other than extending RadioButton?

Comment: I did not find another way to solve it because the radiobutton is an image that you can found in android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-version\data\res\drawable-hdpi\btn_radio and is the image that has transparent margins.
An alternative solution is make your own radiobutton. It's quite simple if you use android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-version\data\res\drawable\btn_radio.xml as a basis.